# Why the name "Dark"?

Tags: dark

The German TV show *Dark* obviously has a certain name. But why was this name chosen?

Typically, the name of a series has a connection with its main plot point. Obviously, the cave that contains the passage between times is dark (duh). But that seems a little mundane, especially compared to the heavy symbolism of something like the name Winden (bind or twine, like a knot might; or like someone's destiny might). The name could simply be because the dome-shaped emanation that appears during the apocalypse is black in color, but seeing as this does not appear until rather late in the series, it seems doubtful.

So what is the significance of the title?

Comment: Possibly helpful; https://www.reddit.com/r/DarK/comments/h0jj48/why_is_the_show_called_dark/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They combined two ideas they were working on and used the title of one of them.

In an interview with Jantje Friese and Baran bo Odar during the 2018 [Berlinale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_International_Film_Festival), Baran bo Odar tells how the show came about. They were asked for a show by Netflix, after turning down Netflix' offer to turn their successful film *[Who Am I – Kein System ist sicher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Am_I_(2014_film))* into a show.

> "We were working on a time travel trilogy back then, but like really big entertaining action movie, and we worked couple years on a show that *was* called 'Dark', another show or movie that was called 'Dark' that was based on the real story of the serial killer Marc Dutroux, who was a serial killer in Belgium in the early nineties, which was really, really, really, really dark as a story."
> [...]
> "We really combined these two ideas. We took the title out of that dark movie 'Dark', and said, let's combine family drama in a small town where kids disappear combined with time travel."

Comment: OK. I will have to reverse my downvote on the other answer,  because, incredibly,  there really is no deeper meaning.

Comment: I will accept it. Mozibur had the idea first, but they were guessing (accurately), whereas this is proof.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't watched the show but I Googled for a description:

> When two children go missing in a small German town, its *sinful* past is exposed with *double* lives and *fractured* relationships that exist amongst four families as they search for the kids...all of whom have a connection to the towns *troubled* history. The story includes *supernatural* elements.

These are typically thought of as dark elements in a story. And this is most likely why the writers called the programme 'Dark'. After all, writers choose words for their emotional resonance, especially in drama.

Comment: I thought about that, clearly,  but that's even more generic. It would be like calling a show "Happy" because it had light comedic elements.  Writers are usually at least a little more clever than that.

Comment: @Adamant [Goes to check IMDb for any shows called *Happy*] [Here](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2452242/) you go, although not really called that because everyone is happy, I’d imagine. But there is also *Happy Days*, which is a bit on the nose! Maybe you give writers too much credit!

Comment: @Adamant: hmmm, however you chose to say 'the cave that contains the passage between times is dark'. Which,  even you admit is banal. Though you appear not to know the word, substituting the word 'doh'  for this.

Comment: You caught me! Thanks for teaching me a new word.

Comment: It appears that,  incredibly,  the writers really did just pick the name for exactly this reason.  If you edit your answer I will be able to upvote it.

Comment: @Adamant - The writers of *Friends* would beg to differ

Comment: @Adamant: Why is that so surprising? Look at how Tolkien chose the word Mordor, which sounds like murder. And that's used to clue people in what to expect emotionally. It's the same reason why so many villains wear black.

Comment: Because they talked about dark matter so much, I thought that had to be it. And I really wanted to give them a bit more credit for the name. Just naming a series after its stylistic traits feels so bland.

Answer (score 0):

German sciences (quantum mechanics)are greatly intertwined with the Indian physics...there are more Germans who knows Sanskrit than Indians. This show is about 'time'. In Sanskrit Time is called as 'Kaala'. Kaala also means 'Dark' or 'Black' in same language. Essentially Vedas doesn't differentiate much between Time and dark.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could greatly improve this answer by editing it to include some relevant citations.